# Find a series of the same number in a List

Tags: c#, .net

I have a List of items containing either 1 or 0, I'm looking to output the items only where there are six 1's back to back in the list. So only write to the console if the item in this list is part of a group of six.

1
1
1
1
1
1
0
1
1
1
 0

In the above list, the first six items would be output but the bottom set of three 1s would not as they are not part of a group of six.

Is this a job for LINQ or RegEx?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How is your output differs from expected output?

Comment: What if there are 7 1's together? Do I output all 7? Do I output two groups of 6? Is a run of 12 1's considered two groups of 6, or is it 7 groups of 6?

Comment: If there are 7 or more 1s then that can be output too, just not below 6. Apologies I did not make that clear. I've tried this in a loop where I loop foreach item in the list, if it is 1 I add it to an array and then check the size of the array, if it is not 6 keep looping, if it 6 then output the array. However, this will only satisfy one group in the list, it will stop after a group of 6, what if it is 7 then it wouldn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate all values into string, then split it by zeros. From substrings select those which have at least 6 characters:

```
List<int> values = new List<int> { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };

var series = String.Concat(values)
                   .Split(new[] { '0' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   .Where(s => s.Length >= 6);
```

For given input data series will contain single item `"111111"` which you can output to console.

Answer (score 1):

Classic run length encoding, O(n), lazy evaluated, stack agnostic, generic for any equatable type.

```
public void TestRunLength()
{
    var runs = new List<int>{ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 0, 4};

    var finalGroup = RunLength(runs).FirstOrDefault(i => i.Count == 6 && i.First() == 1);
}

private IEnumerable<List<T>> RunLength<T>(IEnumerable<T> source) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    T current = default(T);

    var requiresInit = true;

    var list = new List<T>();

    foreach (var i in source)
    {
        if (requiresInit)
        {
            current = i;

            requiresInit = false;
        }

        if (i.Equals(current))
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }
        else
        {
            yield return list;

            list = new List<T>{ i };

            current = i;
        }
    }

    if (list.Any())
    {
        yield return list;
    }
}
```

And because it's lazy it works on infinite sequences  (yes I know its not infinite, but it is large)!

```
public void TestRunLength()
{
    var random = new Random();

    var runs = Enumerable.Range(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue)
                         .Select(i => random.Next(0, 10));

    var finalGroup = RunLength(runs)
        .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Count == 6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it can be done with Regex too if you concatenate your numbers into a string. But I would prefer linq:

```
var bits = new List<int> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0};

int bitCountPerGroup = 6;
var result = bits                    // (1)        (2)
            .Select((x,idx) => bits.Skip(idx).TakeWhile(y => y == x))
            .Where(g => g.Count() == bitCountPerGroup); // (3)

foreach (var set in result)
     Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", set));
```

This code gets a number-set for each number by starting from the number (1) and taking the next numbers as long as they are *equal* (2). Then filter the groups and gets only those groups which have 6 numbers (3).

Answer (score 0):

If for example your list is of an unknown size,or better,you do not know the items in it you could do this recursive example(note that i placed more zeros so it would fetch 2 sets of data,it works with yours also),and pass to the method the amout to group by:

```
//this is the datastructure to hold the results
static List<KeyValuePair<string, List<int>>> Set = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<int>>>();

private static void GetData(List<int> lst, int group)
{
    int count = 1;

    int pivot = lst.First();

    if (lst.Count < group)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (int i in lst.Skip(1))
        {
            if (i == pivot)
            {
                count++;
            }
            else if (count == group)
            {
                Set.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, List<int>>("Set of items " + pivot, lst.Take(count).ToList()));
                GetData(lst.Skip(count).ToList(), group);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                GetData(lst.Skip(count).ToList(), group);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in Main():

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     List<int> test = new List<int> { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
     GetData(test, 6);
     foreach (var item in Set)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("\t" + item.Key);
         foreach (var subitem in item.Value)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(subitem);
         }
     }
}
```